# Read xls , xlsx file in Android Nougat from file manager

Tags: android, csv, android-room, xlsx, xls

**Hi i want to read XLS and XLSX file in android and store in DB.** 
I was trying to read **xls** file in android Nougat

My Code is Here

```
 public static void readXLSXFile(FileInputStream fileInputStream) throws IOException
    {
//        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Test.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

        while (rows.hasNext())
        {
            row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext())
            {
                cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();
                Log.d(TAG, "readXLSXFile: " + cell.getStringCellValue());
               /* if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                {
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                }
                else
                {
                    //U Can Handel Boolean, Formula, Errors
                }*/
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Here is My Code Read Xlsx file from input stream

Comment: What have you tried out so far?

Comment: Read this link https://www.blueappsoftware.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-android-tutorial/

Comment: XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

        XSSFWorkbook test = new XSSFWorkbook();

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;

        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

Comment: @Squti i had also gone through but getting error   **Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;**

Comment: Please put the code you've written and the errors you've gotten *directly in the question*, not as comments

Comment: @Das_Geek Please check now i add my code in question